# List character device programmatically

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel, driver

In my code NVRAM is implemented as character device and I want to give a condition to check whether it is character device or not. How to implement it programmatically? How can I do it through c++ code.

In terminal I gave command `cat /proc/devices` and it lists:

```
Character devices:
  1 mem
  4 /dev/vc/0
  4 tty
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/nvram
```

What does this number 5 in `/dev/nvram` denote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number denotes the device's major number, and the `Character devices:` heading in that listing tells you it's a character device.

If your character device is linked into the filesystem somewhere, like `/dev/mydevice`, you can also get information about it via the `stat` system call. The `st_mode` field of the `struct stat` structure can be tested with the `S_ISCHR` macro.

Comment: I Am not understanding your coment for testing aganist S_ISCHAR. How can I do that.

Comment: Programatically, you test it with the http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat system call. In command line, with `ls`or `stat` command.